# "Град Петров" — какая часть речи?

Tags: морфология

***Красуйся, град Петров, и стой неколебимо, как Россия.***

Какой частью речи выражено слово "Петров"?

Comment: Какой "будет", сказать трудно: слово уже является частью речи "притяжательное прилагательное" :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Название города ***Петербург*** включает имя Петра, но сочетание ***град Петров*** является не собственным, а нарицательным, оно имеет значение ***город Петра; город, построенный Петром.***

***Петров*** – притяжательное прилагательное, написание с прописной буквы, как и само имя (сравнить: Маша, Машина куртка).